# Unilateral error bars in plotly stacked bar chart

Tags: python, plotly, confidence-interval, stacked-bar-chart

How can I get unilateral error bars in the stacked bar chart in plotly below?

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

y1_values = [5, 4, 4, 5, 6, 5]
y2_values = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4]
y3_values = [4, 6, 7, 7, 7, 9]

y1_errors = [0.5, 0.6, 0.4, 0.7, 0.5, 0.8]
y2_errors = [0.4, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 0.5]
y3_errors = [0.6, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4]

fig = go.Figure()
# config = dict({'scrollZoom': True})


# Bars for increase with error bars
fig.add_bar(x=[1, 1.5, 2.2, 2.7, 3.4, 3.9], y=y3_values, name="Increase", marker_color='#FF6692',
            error_y=dict(type="data", array=y3_errors, thickness=2, width=10),
            base=[sum(x) for x in zip(y1_values, y2_values)]
            )

# Bars for decrease with error bars
fig.add_bar(x=[1, 1.5, 2.2, 2.7, 3.4, 3.9], y=y2_values, name="Decrease", marker_color='#19D3F3',
            error_y=dict(type="data", array=y2_errors, thickness=2, width=10),
            base=y1_values
            )

# Bars for unchanged with error bars
fig.add_bar(x=[1, 1.5, 2.2, 2.7, 3.4, 3.9], y=y1_values, name="Unchanged", marker_color='#00CC96',
            error_y=dict(type="data", array=y1_errors, thickness=2, width=10),
            base=[0] * 6
            )

# Annotation for bar1 and bar2
fig.add_annotation(text="10 minutes",
                   xref="paper", yref="paper",
                   x=0.07, y=-0.18,
                   showarrow=False,
                   font_size=20
                   )

# Annotation for bar3 and bar4
fig.add_annotation(text="30 minutes",
                   xref="paper", yref="paper",
                   x=0.5, y=-0.18,
                   showarrow=False,
                   font_size=20
                   )

# Annotation for bar5 and bar6
fig.add_annotation(text="60 minutes",
                   xref="paper", yref="paper",
                   x=0.93, y=-0.18,
                   showarrow=False,
                   font_size=20
                   )

# Layout
fig.update_layout(barmode="stack", showlegend=True, template='plotly_white',
                  height=700,
                  width=1000,
                  legend=dict(title='', orientation="h", traceorder='normal', x=0.46, y=1.05,
                              bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)', bordercolor='rgba(0,0,0,1)', borderwidth=0,
                              font_size=20
                              )
                  )

fig.update_yaxes(showline=True, showgrid=False, linewidth=0.5, linecolor='black',
                 title='<b>Percent</b>', titlefont=dict(size=24), title_standoff=30,
                 ticks='outside',
                 dtick=2,
                 ticklen=10,
                 tickfont=dict(size=20),
                 range=[0, 20]
                 )

fig.update_xaxes(title='', tickvals=[1, 1.5, 2.2, 2.7, 3.4, 3.9],
                 ticktext=["<b>Cat</b><br>n = 15", "<b>Dog</b><br>n = 15",
                           "<b>Cat</b><br>n = 15", "<b>Dog</b><br>n = 15",
                           "<b>Cat</b><br>n = 15", "<b>Dog</b><br>n = 15"],
                 ticks="", tickfont_size=20, linecolor="black", linewidth=1
                 )

fig.show()
```

gives

[image: stacked bar chart with bidirectional error bars]

I would like to have the following (modified in Illustrator)

[image: stacked bar chart with bidirectional error bars, modified]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `arrayminus` to adjust the desired plotting behaviour:

```
fig.add_bar(x=[1, 1.5, 2.2, 2.7, 3.4, 3.9], y=y3_values, name="Increase", marker_color='#FF6692',
            error_y=dict(
                type="data",
                symmetric=False,
                array=y1_errors,
                arrayminus=[0] * 6,  # No negative errors
                thickness=2,
                width=10,
            ),
            base=[sum(x) for x in zip(y1_values, y2_values)],
            )
```

Gives

[image]

The documentation for adjusting error bars can be found at https://plotly.com/python/error-bars/

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. Unfortunately, `arrayminus`does not help, since the horizontal line of the error bar still remains. Please compare your figure to the one I modified in Illustrator.

Comment: That one is not possible in `plotly` from what i understand.

Comment: That is what I understood too _and_ the reason _why_ I am asking.

Comment: It would greatly benefit the quality of your question to add what you have tried already and attach links to the documentation, clarifying your intent.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help! At least I now found a _workaround_.

Answer (score 1):

Just figured that, as a workaround, we can draw a line around the stacked bars that matches in *color* and *width* those of the error bars and together with `symmetric=False` and `arrayminus=[0]` that will hide the lower error bars.

```
import plotly.graph_objects as go

y1_values = [5, 4, 4, 5, 6, 5]
y2_values = [9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4]
y3_values = [4, 6, 7, 7, 7, 9]

y1_errors = [0.5, 0.6, 0.4, 0.7, 0.5, 0.8]
y2_errors = [0.4, 0.3, 0.5, 0.7, 0.3, 0.5]
y3_errors = [0.6, 0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 0.4, 0.4]

fig = go.Figure()
# config = dict({'scrollZoom': True})


# Bars for increase with error bars
fig.add_bar(x=[1,1.5,2.2,2.7,3.4,3.9,4.6,5.1],y=y3_values, name="Increase",
            marker_color='rgba(250, 2, 238, 0.8)', opacity=1,
            marker_line_color='rgba(0,0,0,1)', marker_line_width=2,
            error_y=dict(type="data", array=y3_errors,
                         symmetric=False, arrayminus=[0] * 8,
                         color='rgba(0,0,0,1)', thickness=2, width=10),
            base=[sum(x) for x in zip(y1_values, y2_values)]
           )

# Bars for decrease with error bars
fig.add_bar(x=[1,1.5,2.2,2.7,3.4,3.9,4.6,5.1],y=y2_values, name="Decrease",
            marker_color='rgba(20, 152, 252, 0.8)', opacity=1,
            marker_line_color='rgba(0,0,0,1)', marker_line_width=2,
            error_y=dict(type="data", array=y2_errors,
                         symmetric=False, arrayminus=[0] * 8,
                         color='rgba(0,0,0,1)', thickness=2, width=10),
            base=y1_values
           )

# Bars for unchanged with error bars
fig.add_bar(x=[1,1.5,2.2,2.7,3.4,3.9,4.6,5.1],y=y1_values, name="Unchanged",
            marker_color='rgba(2, 250, 27, 0.8)', opacity=1,
            marker_line_color='rgba(0,0,0,1)', marker_line_width=2,
            error_y=dict(type="data", array=y1_errors,
                         symmetric=False, arrayminus=[0] * 8,
                         color='rgba(0,0,0,1)', thickness=2, width=10),
            base=[0]*6
           )

# Annotation for bar1 and bar2
fig.add_annotation(text="10 minutes",
                   xref="paper", yref="paper",
                   x=0.07, y=-0.18,
                   showarrow=False,
                   font_size=20
                   )

# Annotation for bar3 and bar4
fig.add_annotation(text="30 minutes",
                   xref="paper", yref="paper",
                   x=0.5, y=-0.18,
                   showarrow=False,
                   font_size=20
                   )

# Annotation for bar5 and bar6
fig.add_annotation(text="60 minutes",
                   xref="paper", yref="paper",
                   x=0.93, y=-0.18,
                   showarrow=False,
                   font_size=20
                   )

# Layout
fig.update_layout(barmode="stack", showlegend=True, template='plotly_white',
                  height=700,
                  width=1000,
                  legend=dict(title='', orientation="h", traceorder='normal', x=0.46, y=1.05,
                              bgcolor='rgba(0,0,0,0)', bordercolor='rgba(0,0,0,1)', borderwidth=0,
                              font_size=20
                              )
                  )

fig.update_yaxes(showline=True, showgrid=False, linewidth=0.5, linecolor='black',
                 title='<b>Percent</b>', titlefont=dict(size=24), title_standoff=30,
                 ticks='outside',
                 dtick=2,
                 ticklen=10,
                 tickfont=dict(size=20),
                 range=[0, 20]
                 )

fig.update_xaxes(title='', tickvals=[1, 1.5, 2.2, 2.7, 3.4, 3.9],
                 ticktext=["<b>Cat</b><br>n = 15", "<b>Dog</b><br>n = 15",
                           "<b>Cat</b><br>n = 15", "<b>Dog</b><br>n = 15",
                           "<b>Cat</b><br>n = 15", "<b>Dog</b><br>n = 15"],
                 ticks="", tickfont_size=20, linecolor="black", linewidth=1
                 )

fig.show()
```

gives rise to [image]

Comment: this is brilliant, good job!